Does GDP include value of raw materials in inventory stock?
We know that
Value addition = Value of Output - Intermediate consumption
Value of output of a firm = Sales + change in firm's inventory stock.
And firm's inventory stock equals to finished goods, semi-finished goods and raw material.
So in calculating GDP with Product method, do we also include value of those raw materials which are in firm's inventory?
